# adding values array list from a IEnumerable list

Tags: c#

I have the following code.

```
public IEnumerable<int> BillLevel { get; set; }
```

I want to add values like this

```
BillLevel = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
```

What is the right syntax to assign an array of int to this list?

Comment: How about using AddRange

Comment: How about using an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is an Interface so first you need to declare it with a class which implements `IEnumerable` like `List` and then simply add to list.

```
public IEnumerable<int> BillLevel { get; set; }

BillLevel = new List<int>();
BillLevel.AddRange(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

Or you can Add the numbers in declaration

```
BillLevel = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: Did the trick thank you! Now I want a value to display it on the view. I use angularJS ng-model="//get selected value in combobox" ng-options="//billevel"

Answer (score 0):

This intilalizes the BillLevel property with an array of intergers.

```
BillLevel = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to pass the reference of a class which implement IEnumerable Interface.
Such as List Class implement this interface 
so 
you can pass the instance of List of int into this

```
public IEnumerable<int> BillLevel { get; set; }

BillLevel = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: Thanks man ! Is there a way to set BillLevel on index 3 for example ? (default value)